# how to resize navbar differently on different screens when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I want to resize my navbar differently on different window sizes, but when I use the following code to do so, when I scroll back up on a mobile device, the size of the navbar becomes what it is supposed to be on the desktop version on scrolling back up (second elseif statement). How do I make the conditioning so that when I scroll back up, the navbar resizes according to the 4th case , which is for mobiles.

```
function scrollFunction() {
      if (
        window.innerWidth>815 &&
        document.body.scrollTop > 80 ||
        document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80 
      ) {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "30px 50px";
        document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "32px";
      } else if (        
        window.innerWidth>815 &&
        document.body.scrollTop < 80 ||
        document.documentElement.scrollTop < 80 )
         {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "60px 50px";
        document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "38px";
      }
      else if(
        widnow.innerWidth<815 &&
        document.body.scrollTop > 80 ||
        document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80 
      ){
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "30px 40px";
        document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "32px";
      }
      else if (
        window.innerWidth<815 &&
        document.body.scrollTop < 80 ||
        document.documentElement.scrollTop < 80 
      ){
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "30px 40px";
        document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "32px";
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML and CSS as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&&` has precedence over `||`. So I think given your set of conditions, the last two conditions are less likely to get invoked.

Try

```
if (
        window.innerWidth>815 &&
        (document.body.scrollTop > 80 ||
        document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80)
      ) {
```

instead

```
if (
        window.innerWidth>815 &&
        document.body.scrollTop > 80 ||
        document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80 
      ) {
```

on all your `if` and `else if` conditions.

Also, for tasks like this, I would urge you to look into [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

Comment: Thanks! this works for me, also , I didnt use media queries because I did not know how to track the scrolbar there , but thank you anyways